# is neovim's command mode compatible with ANSI color codes output by shell? If yes, how to enable it?

Tags: neovim

I set the default shell of neovim v0.9.1 to PowerShell v7.3 (installed using chocolatey, filename is pwsh.exe) instead of usual Command Prompt. The init.vim config is

```
if executable("pwsh")
" Set PowerShell as the shell for running external ! commands
    set shell=pwsh.exe
    set shellcmdflag=-NoProfile\ -NoLogo\ -NonInteractive\ -Command
    set shellquote="\""
    " shellxquote must be a literal space character.
    set shellxquote=" "

endif
```

But now the problem is, running shell commands in command mode is not supporting the ANSI color codes:

[image: here's how using !dir in command mode].

It does not work in both gui version or command line version.

However when the shell is opened through `:terminal` command in nvim, it does perfectly work fine:

[image: like this using same !dir]

I thought its some kind of bug, tried to remove the PowerShell as shell and it worked perfectly fine with the default Command Prompt shell.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and I'm still looking for solution.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled ANSI color settings by adding `$PSStyle.OutputRendering = [System.Management.Automation.OutputRendering]::PlainText` in settings:

```
if (vim.fn.has "win32") == 1 then
    local_vim.opt.shell = "pwsh"
    local_vim.opt.shellcmdflag =
      "-NoProfile -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command [Console]::InputEncoding=[Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new();$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding']='utf8';$PSStyle.OutputRendering = [System.Management.Automation.OutputRendering]::PlainText;"
    local_vim.opt.shellredir = '2>&1 | %%{ "$_" } | Out-File %s; exit $LastExitCode'
    local_vim.opt.shellpipe = '2>&1 | %%{ "$_" } | Tee-Object %s; exit $LastExitCode'
    local_vim.opt.shellquote = ""
    local_vim.opt.shellxquote = ""
  end
```